# Updated Linux Alternative to Stereo Mix broadcasting?

Tags: linux, broadcast

I am quite certain this question has been asked before. However, seeing as many of the distro's have come out with Major updates, & LTS Distros as well.

I wonder if anyone has found a more efficient way to broadcast audio, much like you would find with the Stereo Mix on Windows where you would have Stereo mix listening to your Audio Output etc?

I do some DJing myself, and the medium in which I do this has its own means of broadcasting audio, much like you do in skype. Very few of us have ever mastered the level of clarity that I have with my broadcasts, and I have found the Linux clarity not up to my standards.

So in long story short, I am seeking an efficient Linux alternative to Stereo Mix, updated to current codes.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more concretely what exactly you want to do? Use Linux as a streaming media server? There's e.g. `icecast`. Record exactly what comes out of your stereo speakers? Use the `*.monitor` Pulseaudio sources. Downmix your 5.1 sound output to stereo, permanently? Use a Pulseaudio module. Improve the "clarity" of the sound? I guess you need an equalizer, e.g. LDSPA plugins. Etc. Is there an easy GUI that does all of that at the press of a button? No, but it would't be difficult to write it.